# Не могу найти ошибку в вычислениях

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток!

Начал модифицировать свой код, который берет данные из txt файла, преобразовывает его в матрицу(граф) и реализует алгоритм Дейкстры.

Модификация в том, чтобы код считал абсолютно каждый путь. Путь выбирает код правильно, но считает он не понятно как.

Уточнение: Пути, такие как 0 --> 0, 1 --> 1 и т.д., считает правильно.

Сам код:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

"""Импортируем из txt файла матрицу"""


def creating_a_matrix():
    file_table_matrix_txt = open('table_matrix_DM.txt', 'r')
    string_table_matrix = file_table_matrix_txt.read()
    list_table_matrix = list(string_table_matrix.split('\n'))
    matrix = []
    for element_list_table_matrix in list_table_matrix:
        matrix.append(element_list_table_matrix.split(' '))

    matrix = [[int(i) for i in j] for j in matrix]
    matrix = [tuple(i) for i in matrix]
    matrix = tuple(matrix)
    file_table_matrix_txt.close()
    return matrix


"""Создаем словарь. Смотреть Рис..."""
graph = {i: [(y, j) for j, y in enumerate(x) if y] or [(None, None)] for i, x in enumerate(creating_a_matrix())}

"""Алгоритм Дейкстры"""


def dijkstra(start, goal, graph, element_graph):
    queue = []
    heappush(queue, (graph[start][element_graph][0], start))
    cost_visited = {start: graph[start][element_graph][0]}
    visited = {start: graph[start][element_graph][0]}
    while queue:
        cur_cost, cur_node = heappop(queue)

        if cur_node == goal:
            break

        next_nodes = graph[cur_node]

        for next_node in next_nodes:
            neigh_cost, neigh_node = next_node
            new_cost = cost_visited[cur_node] + neigh_cost

            if neigh_node not in cost_visited or new_cost < cost_visited[neigh_node]:
                heappush(queue, (new_cost, neigh_node))
                cost_visited[neigh_node] = new_cost
                visited[neigh_node] = cur_node
    return visited, cur_cost


def all_paths():
    start = 0
    goal = 0
    element_graph = 0
    while start != 7:
        while goal != 7:
            visited, cur_cost = dijkstra(start, goal, graph, element_graph)
            cur_node = goal
            print(f'\nПуть от {start} до {goal}: составляет {cur_cost} единиц.\nПуть:   {goal}', end=' ')
            while cur_node != start:
                cur_node = visited[cur_node]
                print(f'<--- {cur_node} ', end='')
            element_graph += 1
            goal += 1
        element_graph = 0
        start += 1
        goal = 0


all_paths()
```

txt содержит такие данные:[image: Данные из txt файла]

Работа кода:

[image: Вывод]

Прошу помочь!

P.S.

Если вы хотите запустить код, нужно будет сначала вести данные в Excel и скопировать их в txt файл, ибо разделяются данные не пробелом а табуляцией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После бессонной ночи, я догадался!
Работает

Вот исправленный код:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

"""Импортируем из txt файла матрицу"""


def creating_a_matrix():
    file_table_matrix_txt = open('table_matrix_DM.txt', 'r')
    string_table_matrix = file_table_matrix_txt.read()
    list_table_matrix = list(string_table_matrix.split('\n'))
    matrix = []
    for element_list_table_matrix in list_table_matrix:
        matrix.append(element_list_table_matrix.split(' '))

    matrix = [[int(i) for i in j] for j in matrix]
    matrix = [tuple(i) for i in matrix]
    matrix = tuple(matrix)
    file_table_matrix_txt.close()
    return matrix


"""Создаем словарь. Смотреть Рис..."""
graph = {i: [(y, j) for j, y in enumerate(x) if y] or [(None, None)] for i, x in enumerate(creating_a_matrix())}

"""Алгоритм Дейкстры"""


def dijkstra(start, goal, graph, element_graph):
    queue = []
    if start == goal:
        heappush(queue, (graph[start][element_graph][0], start))
        cost_visited = {start: graph[start][element_graph][0]}
        visited = {start: graph[start][element_graph][0]}
    else:
        heappush(queue, (0, start))
        cost_visited = {start: 0}
        visited = {start: None}
    while queue:
        cur_cost, cur_node = heappop(queue)

        if cur_node == goal:
            break

        next_nodes = graph[cur_node]

        for next_node in next_nodes:
            neigh_cost, neigh_node = next_node
            new_cost = cost_visited[cur_node] + neigh_cost

            if neigh_node not in cost_visited or new_cost < cost_visited[neigh_node]:
                heappush(queue, (new_cost, neigh_node))
                cost_visited[neigh_node] = new_cost
                visited[neigh_node] = cur_node
    return visited, cur_cost


def all_paths():
    start = 0
    goal = 0
    element_graph = 0
    while start != 7:
        while goal != 7:
            visited, cur_cost = dijkstra(start, goal, graph, element_graph)
            cur_node = goal
            print(f'\nПуть от {start} до {goal}: составляет {cur_cost} единиц.\nПуть:   {goal}', end=' ')
            while cur_node != start:
                cur_node = visited[cur_node]
                print(f'<--- {cur_node} ', end='')
            element_graph += 1
            goal += 1
        element_graph = 0
        start += 1
        goal = 0


all_paths()
```